# linq query to fetch the data by increment 0.50

Tags: c#

In my database table xyz I have two fields abc and pqr.

abc is `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8` and pqr is `12.11,13.13,14.12,15.12,16.14,17.12,18.21,19.12`. Now I want to fetch the records on the basis of the abc by the increment of .5.

For example if 1 then 12.11, 1.5 then avgof pqr for 1 and 2.and want to do it using linq query.

Comment: How have you done this without linq? What have you tried?

Comment: I have done it using the for loop but query takes time to execute.

Comment: Why not post your for-loop? It would give us al more insight in what you wish to achieve

Comment: Using LINQ is pretty well the same as doing it with a loop. It's just framework-level syntactic sugar, really. Could you post the loop you were using?

Comment: Also, I'm not sure I see the relevance of `abc` here. Is it meant to be a sequential list of numbers, or is that just a bad example? Are we reading the "index" numbers from it that field, like is that where `1`, `1.5`, etc. are meant to be coming from?

Comment: var mTurbinecurve1 = mTurbineCurve.GroupBy(f => new { dWindSpeed = (iStepSize == 1) ? Math.Ceiling(f.dXAxis) : ((iStepSize == (decimal)0.5) ? Math.Floor(f.dXAxis)+(decimal)0.5 : (Math.Round(f.dXAxis / (decimal)0.25)) * (decimal)0.25) })
                      .Select(g => new GroupedData
                      {                          
                          dGroupValue1 = (double)(g.Key.dWindSpeed),
                          dGroupValue2 = (double)(g.Average(k=> k.dYAxis))}).OrderBy(f => f.dGroupValue1).ToList();      Something like thison the basis of the step size 1,0.5 or 0.25

Comment: Click the edit button and update your question to include the code. - And include what isn't working currently.

Comment: Please explain *why* something should happen, not just *that* it should happen. "For example if 1 then 12.11" <-- why? How does 1 imply 12.11?

Comment: in the data base for the dXAxis 1 there is dYAxis 12.23 same as other values are there.so I want to fetch the record for each diff of 0.5 or 0.25

Answer (score 0):

Something in the lines of:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{

var abc = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };
var pqr = new[] { 12.11, 13.13, 14.12, 15.12, 16.14, 17.12, 18.21, 19.12 };

var values = abc.Take(abc.Length - 1).ToDictionary(
    o => 0.5 + o,
    o => new[]
{
    pqr.Skip(1).ToList()[o], 
    pqr.Take(pqr.Length - 1).ToList()[o]
}.Average());
abc.ToList().ForEach(o => values.Add(o, pqr[o]));
```

To display values:

```
foreach (var value in values.Keys)
{
    Trace.WriteLine(string.Format("Key:{0} Value:{1}", value, values[value]));
}
```